# Shortest path in Graph with time limit

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path

Let's say I have a graph `G` with `N` vertices and `M` edges. Each edge has its length and time (let's say in minutes), which it takes to traverse that edge. I need to find the shortest path in the graph between the vertices `1` and `N`, which is performed in under `T` minutes time.
Since time is the more valuable resource and we care about traversing the graph in time, and only then with minimal length, I decided to use Dijkstra's algorithm, for which I considered the time of each edge as its weight. I added a vector to store the durations. Thus, the algorithm returns the least time, not the least length. A friend suggested this addition to my code:

```cpp
int answer(int T) {
    int l = 1;
    int r = M; // a very big number
    int answer = M;
    while (l <= r) {
        int mid = (l + r) / 2;
        int time = dijkstra(mid); // the parameter mid serves as an upper bound for dijkstra and I relax the edge only if its length(not time) is less than mid
        if (time <= T) {
            answer = mid;
            r = mid - 1;
        } else {
            l = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    if (best == M) {
        return -1; // what we return in case there is no path in the graph, which takes less than T minutes
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Here is the `dijkstra` method (part of class `Graph` with `std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<Node>> adjacencyList member`):

```cpp
int dijkstra(int maxLength) {
        std::priority_queue<Node, std::vector<Node>, NodeComparator> heap;//NodeComparator sorts by time of edge
        std::vector<int> durations(this->numberOfVertices + 1, M);
        std::set<int> visited;
        // duration 1->1 is 0
        durations[1] = 0;
        heap.emplace(1, 0, 0);
        while (!heap.empty()) {
            int vertex = heap.top().endVertex;
            heap.pop();
            // to avoid repetition
            if (visited.find(vertex) != visited.end()) {
                continue;
            }
            for (Node node: adjacencyList[vertex]) {
                // relaxation
                if (node.length <= maxLength && durations[node.endVertex] > durations[vertex] + node.time) {
                    durations[node.endVertex] = durations[vertex] + node.time;
                    heap.emplace(node.endVertex, durations[node.endVertex], 0);
                }
            }
            // mark as visited to avoid going through the same vertex again
            visited.insert(vertex);
        }
        // return path time between 1 and N bounded by maxKilograms
        return durations.back();
    }
```

This seems to work but seems inefficient to me. To be frank, I don't understand his idea completely. It appears to me like randomly trying to find the best answer(because nobody said that the time of an edge is tied proportionally to its length). I tried searching for `shortest path in graph with time limit` but I found algorithms that find the *fastest* paths, not the *shortest* with a limit. Does an algorithm for this even exist? How can improve my solution?

Comment: What does the function dijkstra ? What do you expect your function answer to return ?
Where does "best" variable comes from ? The algorithm seems to use a binary search, but it's hard to graps with so little information. Please edit your question regarding your code.
A quick solution to your problem would be to modify the dijkstra algorithm so that any path taking more time than allowed as a weight of "infinite". One pass should do the trick, but be sure to check that the answer is valid in the end.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope the information is sufficient now. Thanks for looking into my question.

Answer (score 0):

What is this?

```
int time = dijkstra(mid);
```

It certainly isnt an implementation of the Dijkstra algorithm!

The Dijkstra algorithm requires the starting node and returns THE shortest path from the starting node to every other.

You are going to need a function that returns all the distinct paths between start and end nodes that take less than T.  Then you can search them for the one that is cheapest.

```
Search graph for all distinct paths from start to end
Discard paths that take more then T
Select cheapest path.
```

Comment: it's dijkstra but directly returns the distances between 1 and every other vertex. That's why it doesn't take any source. It is hardcoded to be 1.

Comment: How?  It seems to be returning a single integer!

Comment: Yes. I didn't phrase myself correctly. Since I need only the distance between vertexes 1 and N, I directly return the last element of the vector (which is the distance between 1 and N). I edited my answer, so now you should be able to see the dijkstra() method

Answer (score 0):

Finding a resource constrained shortest path is NPHard. Most approaches to this problem employ a labelling scheme, which is a specialization of dynamic programming. You could use available libraries to accomplish this. See [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/graph/doc/r_c_shortest_paths.html) for a boost implementation.